# Word Add-in content of document

Tags: javascript, office-js

I'm to get the get the data from word document and setting it as global use for my javascript. But I get this error with the following code

> you are not able to set the body content to a global variable

```
var bodyText;
getData();

function getData() {
    Word.run(function (context) {

        var body = context.document.body;

        context.load(body, 'text');

        return context.sync().then(function () {
            bodyText = body.text;
        });
    });

    console.log(bodyText);
}

console.log(bodyText);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first console.log is unreachable code because the method returns before that line is reached. The other problem is that `Word.run` is asynchronous and hasn't completed by the time your second console.log is invoked, so the second one returns undefined. The following code works:

```
var bodyText;
getData();

function getData() {
    return Word.run(function (context) {
        var body = context.document.body;

        context.load(body, 'text');

        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                bodyText = body.text;
                console.log(bodyText); //Completes second and works
            });
    });
   // console.log(bodyText); // Unreachable code
}
console.log(bodyText); // Completes first and returns undefined
```

You can get control of the synchronization by putting the second console.log in a `then` method that is chained to the call of `getData`:

```
var bodyText;
getData().then(function () {
    console.log(bodyText); // Completes second and works
});

function getData() {
    return Word.run(function (context) {
        var body = context.document.body; 

        context.load(body, 'text');

        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                bodyText = body.text;
                console.log(bodyText); //Completes first and works
            });
    });
}
```